# Syntax-dependent fonts in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, unicode, fonts

Notepad++ has the ability to show some types of syntax (e.g. strings) in a different font from others.
Can Eclipse do something like this?

I need this ability because the strings have Unicode characters in them, but all the fonts that I have that support Unicode look crap in the rest of the code.

**EDIT**: I am looking for this feature for Java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not currently possible, you can only change the font family for the entire Java editor.

Answer (score 0):

it depends on which perspective .. I am using PyDev .. go to window-->preferences then select PyDev tab then select Editor ..you will find a panel titled with "Appearance color options" .. you can customize the color of each part of your codes

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned it: I am looking for this for Java code.

Comment: should be the same way .. isn't?

Comment: Under General -> Appearanace -> Colors and Fonts -> Java, there is nothing related to different types of syntax. Under Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring there is nothing related to fonts. Did I miss something?